# Redis client using nodejs how to check if connection is valid

Tags: node.js, redis

Is there a proper way to check every few minutes if my connection to redis is still valid and alive?
I have an issue where every few hours (could be a day) that my connection to redis is disconnected and it doesn't reconnect, even if it set to reconnect. I want to manually check if the connection is still valid and if not, I can reconnect to redis again.

Answer (score -2):

Generally Nodejs and Redis does not have any connections issue, i am using ioredis lib for quite long time and did not any disconnect issue.

you can ping the redis and redis will response with pong to check connection in live or not.

Comment: What if redis running on a remote server?

Comment: ping command will also work on remote server.